# Extract 8-digit numbers from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, text-extraction

I have a list of strings which may contain letters, symbols, digits, etc, as below:

```
list = ['\n', '', '0', '38059', '', '', '?_', '71229366', '', '1', '38059', '', '', '?_', '87640804', '', '2', '38059', '', '', '?_', '71758011', '', '', ':?', ';__', '71229366287640804271758011287169822']
```

How do I filter out all other strings, except numbers less than 10000000 and greater than 99999999?

Expected Output:

```
list = ['71229366', '87640804', '71758011']
```

Comment: what do mean with *all the characters* ?

Comment: here's the output with no characters `[]`

Comment: Try `list = None`

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind making a new list, you can try something with just a list comprehension like

```
filtered_list = [i for i in list if i.isdigit() and 10000000 < int(i) < 99999999]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `map` and `filter`.

```
your_list = ['\n', '', '0', '38059', '', '', '?_', '71229366', '', '1', '38059', 
             '', '', '?_', '87640804', '', '2', '38059', '', '', '?_', '71758011', 
             '', '', ':?', ';__', '71229366287640804271758011287169822']

new_list = list(map(int, filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() and 10000000 < int(x) < 99999999, your_list)))
print(new_list)
```

`list()` optional on python2.

Output:

```
[71229366, 87640804, 71758011]
```

---

If you don't want the conversion to integer, drop the `map`:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() and 10000000 < int(x) < 99999999, your_list))
['71229366', '87640804', '71758011']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def valid(v):
    try:
        value = int(v)
        return 10000000 <= value <= 99999999
    except:
        return False

output = [x for x in list if valid(x)]
```

**Explanation**:

Filter all values in the list using the valid function as your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ['\n', '', '0', '38059', '', '', '?_', '71229366', '', '1', '38059', 
        '', '', '?_', '87640804', '', '2', '38059', '', '', '?_', '71758011', 
        '', '', ':?', ';__', '71229366287640804271758011287169822']

res = []
for e in data:
    try:
        number = int(e)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if 10000000  < number < 99999999:
        res.append(str(number))
```

print(res)

```
print(res)
```

Output:

```
 ['71229366', '87640804', '71758011']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide a **simple and efficient** answer, using regular expressions. There's no need to `map` (duplicating the original list), or to convert everything to `int`s; you are basically asking how **to keep all 8-digit integers** in your list:

```
>>> filter(re.compile('^\d{8}$').match, data)
['71229366', '87640804', '71758011']
```

We [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) a regular expression which matches exactly 8 digits and then filter the list by providing a partial application of [`regex.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) to the standard [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.